# How to send an email using sendmail command in linux

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I tried the below two commands.

1. ```
   From: mail_id
   To: Recipient_mail_id
   Hi, this is my message, and I'm sending it to you!
   .
   ```
2. ```bash
   echo "My message" | sendmail -s subject Recipient_mail_id
   ```

But didn't get any mail to the recipient's mail address.

SMTP server is installed on another server and it is up and running. So can anyone help me out on how to send a test email through that SMTP server using sendmail or smtp commands?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 17):

### **1. Using `sendmail` command:**

Created a file with email content:

```
$ cat /tem/email.txt
```

```
Subject: Terminal Email Send
Email Content line 1
Email Content line 2
```

**Now send email using the following command:**

```
$ sendmail user@example.com < /tem/email.txt
```

### **2. Using `mail` command:**

```bash
$ mail -s "Test Subject" user@example.com < /dev/null
```

**Also, you can send an attachment with this command. Use `-a` for mailx and `-A` for mailutils.**

```bash
$ mail -a /opt/file.sql -s "Backup File" user@example.com < /dev/null
```

**Also, we can add comma separated emails to send the email to multiple recipients together.**

```bash
$ mail -s "Test Email" user@example.com,user2@example.com < /dev/null
```

### **3. Using `mutt` command:**

```bash
$ mutt -s "Test Email" user@example.com < /dev/null
```

**Send an email including an attachment**

```bash
$ mutt -s "Test Email" -a /opt/backup.sql user@example.com < /dev/null
```

Comment: I want to use host name and port of the SMTP server in the command. How to use that?

Comment: This will help you:

echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v -r "someone@example.com" -s "This is the subject" -S smtp="mail.example.com:587" -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="someone@example.com" -S smtp-auth-password="abc123" -S ssl-verify=ignore yourfriend@gmail.com

Answer (score 7):

`sendmail` expects email in "raw" format. Usually it is better to use higher level commands (e.g. `mail`) unless email is trivially simple.
"sendmail look alike" command is provided also by MTA/SMTP servers (postfix/exim/…) and programs like msmtp. Basic sendmail command line options are the facto standard so it may be a good choice for sending simple emails.

You may try the following shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

# sendmail command line optons:
# -i - do not treat lines starting with dot specially
# -t - read recipients lists from message headers: TO,CC,BCC
# -v - use verbose mode (describe what is happening) 
#
# The empty line separates mail headers from mail body

FROM='john.doe@examle.net'
TO='jane.doe@example.com' 
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t << MESSAGE_END
To: ${TO}
From: ${FROM}     

Hi, this is my message, 
and I'm sending it to you! 
MESSAGE_END
```

**WARNING**
Sending text emails with non US-ASCII characters in email body requires extra headers (MIME). Special encoding is required for non US-ASCII characters in email headers.